# How to append uppercase text only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `<h2>` tag that is generated based on an image's alt text. I want to add a style to the parts of the text that are uppercase.

My plan is use javascript / jquery to find the uppercase text and wrap it in a `<strong>` tag, then use css to style this.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure whether I understood you correctly. E.g. your text is "Hello WORLD this is AWESOME!" and you'd like to format "WORLD" and "AWESOME"?

Answer (score 4):

`sometext.match(/[A-Z]+/g)` gives you an array of all uppercase text in a string, so loop that to add style.

To match at least 2 uppercase characters use `.match(/([A-Z]+){2}/g)`

To surround all uppercase string parts with length >= 2 within a string with (for example) `<b></b>` use:

```
sometext.replace(/([A-Z]+){2}/g,function(a){return '<b>'+a+'</b>';});
```

Comment: I'd try to match only uppercase words with at least two characters, but that's essentially up to DanV on what he'd need I guess.

Comment: Uppercase words! Will this regex work for that? I am completely novice  when it comes to regex :P

Comment: @Rakesh: Why don't you just try it? Open up developer tools in your browser and type

`'I am looking for upperCASE WORDS in THIS string'.match(/([A-Z]+){2}/g)`. 

For words only, type:  

`I am looking for upperCASE WORDS in THIS string'.match(/\b([A-Z]+){2}/g)`

Answer (score 1):

```
function findUC() {
    var h2 = $('h2').text();
    var exploded = h2.split(' ');
    var pattern = new RegExp('[^A-Z]');
    var i;
    var style = '';
    for (i = 0; i < exploded.length; i++) {
       if (!exploded[i].match(pattern)) {
           style += '<span style="color:blue;">' + exploded[i] + '<span>';
       } else {
           style += exploded[i];
       }
    }
    $('h2').text(style);
}
findUC();​
```

This will help you. Modify this according to your requirement. Working  [fiddle is here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bvjebin/VpUs4/)

For your requirement you mentioned, I'm editing this answer.

```
function findUC() {
var h2 = $('h2').text();
var exploded = h2.split(' ');
var pattern = new RegExp('[^A-Z]');
var i, j;
var style = '';
var character = '';
for (i = 0; i < exploded.length; i++) {
    if (!exploded[i].match(pattern)) {
        var firstletter = exploded[i].substr(0,1);
        var lastletter = exploded[i].substr(1, exploded[i].length);
        style += firstletter;
        style += '<span style="color:blue;">' + lastletter + '<span>';
    } else {
        style += " "+exploded[i]+" ";
    }
}


   $('h2').text(style);
}
findUC();​
```

Fiddle is mentioned in my last comment. Try it out.

EDIT 3: 
As you mentioned in comments I have modified the fiddle: try this [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bvjebin/VpUs4/8/)

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I've made a few tweaks as it was stripping out all the spaces, and it was writing the tags as text rather than html... I removed the space between the single quotes... var exploded = h2.split(''); which fixed this issue. Is there a way to ignore the first character? See my example... www.revival.graphitewebdesign.co.uk/

Comment: Easy tiger... If you look at the html it is inserting the tags around each letter individually. Is it possible to wrap around the whole word?

Comment: Thanks @Jebin, this is real close. I think you may have misunderstood me though, I meant the first letter of the sentence, not of each word. Apologies for any confusion. This now only works for the first uppercase word and not any others in the H2 tag... www.revival.graphitewebdesign.co.uk

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12256/discussion-between-danv-and-jebin)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to find the uppercase passages. Just some regular expression like `/[A-Z]{2,}/g`. Due to the `{2,}` this will only match at least two uppercase characters following each other. As an alternative, you could use `/\b[A-Z]+\b/g` if you'd like to exclude words like `HELlo`. Once you've got the positions, you can use different approaches to connect/create the HTML code, e.g. `$('<div/>').append(...)`.